# Are there anyway to lock a folder in google drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to prevent everything in the folder from being edit in any way.
Only the admin could turn off the lock when needed.
Are there programmatic ways ( maybe using API) to achieve this?

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, `contentRestrictions`of Drive API cannot be used for the folder. So in your situation, how about changing the permission of the users of the top folder as the reader? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/update) If this was not the direction you expect, I apologize. By the way, can I ask you about the detail of your goal? Because I cannot understand about `programmatic ways` of `Are there programmatic ways ( maybe using API) to achieve this?`. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this in the past by simply setting the permissions on the folder, and all files within the folder to read for every user

You can use the [Permissions.update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/update) method to change the permissions for each user, who currently has access.

You mention admin so i am going to guess you have a Workspace account, i would recommend setting up a service account with delegation access of the admin to be able to monitor this directory.